# Improving the efficiency of slow R code

Tags: r, range, apply, performance

I have an I/GRanges Views object as

** Its a simplified version of the data, actual data is huge

```
Views on a 10000000-length Rle subject

 views:
      start      end   width
 [1]      1     1000    1000 [100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 ...]
 [2]   1001     2000    1000 [190 190 190 190 190 190 190 190 190 190 ...]
 [3]   2001     3000    1000 [280 280 280 280 280 280 280 280 280 280 ...]
 [4]   3001     4000    1000 [370 370 370 370 370 370 370 370 370 370 ...]
 [5]   4001     5000    1000 [460 460 460 460 460 460 460 460 460 460 ...]
 ...    ...      ...     ... ...
 [9996] 995001  9996000 9001000 [89650 89650 89650 89650 89650 89650 ...]
 [9997] 996001  9997000 9001000 [89740 89740 89740 89740 89740 89740 ...]
 [9998] 997001  9998000 9001000 [89830 89830 89830 89830 89830 89830 ...]
 [9999] 998001  9999000 9001000 [89920 89920 89920 89920 89920 89920 ...]
[10000] 999001 10000000 9001000 [90010 90010 90010 90010 90010 90010 ...]
```

Each View(line) has a width of 1000 meaning 1000 datapoints of 100 each.
Now, I would like to divide the set of datapoints into 20 bins (in this case, 50 per bin) and then take the mean, so the output will be a vector of 20 numbers, each being the average at that bin.

Output :

```
[1] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

Now, in a real situation, I have more than 20 views like that, with a different width for each line and some lines > 5K. My code works fine but is very slow, for my data, for each line, returning a vector of 20 bins, takes ~1.5secs and I have >30K lines, making ~12.5 hours.

I am sure, there are ways to fasten these calculations, if not may somehow I can use the parallel nodes of my cluster. What do you suggest.

### Test Code to generate the data :

```
library('GenomicRanges')
# generating data frame 
df=data.frame(chrom=rep('Chr1',100000),start=seq(1,1000000,by=1000),end=seq(1000,10000000,by=1000),strand=rep("+",100000))

# making GRanges object
gr=GRanges(seqnames=as.vector(df[,1]),IRanges(start=df[,2],end=df[,3]),strand=df[,4])
# obtaining coverage using function coverage in the form of RLE object
gr.cov=coverage(gr)
# generating views for specific start and end
gr.views=Views(gr.cov[[1]],start=seq(1,1000000,by=1000),end=seq(1000,10000000,by=1000))
# putting in temp variable
d=gr.views

# this following code calculates the matrix (where each line is 20 points) for 10 lines
# reduce or increase the number in the outermost sapply loop to increase/decrease the lines to be calculated

sapply(1:10,function(j)
   sapply(1:20,
   function(i)as.numeric(
     format(
       mean(
         as(d[[j]][(
           seq(0,length(d[[j]]),floor(length(d[[j]])/20))+1)[i]:
             c((seq(0,length(d[[j]]),floor(length(d[[j]])/20)))[
               -length((seq(0,length(d[[j]]),floor(length(d[[j]])/20))))
               ],length(d[[j]]))[i+1]],
            "RangedData")$score),
       digits=2)
     )
   )
)
```

Comment: if you're able to re-write it as a sql query, use monetdb + r ;) http://usgsd.blogspot.com/2012/11/why-and-how-to-install-monetdb-with-r.html

Comment: Your views do not each have width 1000, can you clarify?

Comment: @MartinMorgan that's even perfect example for my data, I also have  views with different widths which are actually gene lengths :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating views based on genes, why not create views based on the windows on which you want to do the calculations, and then use things like `viewSums` or `viewMaxs` to calculate statistics on the views? Suppose you had a `GRanges` describing the start and end of 'genes' (transcripts?)

```
genes <- GRanges(seqnames, IRanges(geneStarts, geneEnds))
```

You might calcluate the window starts and ends with

```
n <- 50L
starts0 <- Map(function(...) floor(seq(...)), start(genes), end(genes),
               MoreArgs=list(length.out=n + 1L))
ends <- lapply(starts0, function(x) floor(x)[-1])
starts <- lapply(starts0, function(x) x[-length(x)])
```

Then create your Views

```
v <- Views(gr.cov[[1]], start=unlist(starts), end=unlist(ends))
```

(see `?RleViews` for the a "Views,RleList-method") calculate statistics and split by gene

```
split(viewMeans(v), rep(seq_along(genes), each=n))
```

Asking on the [Bioconductor mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list) will likely lead to many clever solutions.

`v` is an instance of the "RleViews" class; `v[[1]]` is an instance of `Rle`. You can calculate `mean(v[[1]])` as confirmation of `viewMeans`, or take it one step further and coerce `v[[1]]` to a plain old vector and calculate that `mean(as.vector(v[[1]])))`. `runValue(v[[1]])` (the same as `v[[1]]@values` but using an appropriate accessor, rather than peeking under the hood) returns the values in the Rle, e.g.,

```
> (x <- Rle(c(rep(100, 10), rep(200, 10))))
numeric-Rle of length 20 with 2 runs
  Lengths:  10  10
  Values : 100 200
> runValue(x)
[1] 100 200
> runLength(x)
[1] 10 10
```

and obviously `mean(runValue(x)) != mean(x)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfect & time is reduced significantly. I edited the code a bit for the bin length and removing the last value from the `starts` variable, as `starts` and `ends` are of unequal length after making the ranges in `lapply` function.

There is only one discrepancy, when I generate the final sub-view using split, the last part, the mean is different from what one would expect. 
`sp=split(viewMeans(v), rep(seq_along(genes), each=n)`
sp[[1]] is different from `m=sapply(1:20,function(x)mean(v[[x]]@values))`

I reduced my bin size from 50 to 20 , what's the explanation for this

Comment: Hey Martin, there is small correction. When you remove last value from `starts` list you actually remove the last list, so `sapply` can be used to remove last value from each list. `starts=lapply(starts0,function(x)x[-length(x)])` & the split is missing `)` bracket.

One thing, which is confusing me is, the diff. of the means. 
Ex. `mean(v[[1]])=0.255` which is calculated using viewMeans is different from `mean(v[[1]]@values)=0.83` which is mean of values for that width. Does viewMeans, include something else as well,I couldn't find in docs & cannot generate the mean manually by any means. Thx

Comment: Thanks Martin, My bad, I was actually taking the mean of the unique values in RLE object, which is ofcourse what I dont want. Thanks for your time, the code is superfast and downscaled the time by 100X :)